# Should workflows run when creating a new item using the data sheet view?

Tags: workflow, datasheet

I have workflow configured to start when an item is created. 
Using the datasheet view, when adding a row, the workflows are not fired.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, definitely not by design. Generically speaking, workflows should run when adding a new item in the datasheet view.

Without knowing the specifics of what workflow method (OOB, SPD, WF, 3rd party, etc.) it's hard to give you a definitive answer.

If you add an item from a non-datasheet view does the workflow kick-off?

Comment: I'm using nintex workflows, and yes when I create a item normaly, (newItem.aspx) the worklows kick off fine.

Comment: You may want to contact Nintex support and see if there are any known issues here. I wouldn't expect they are doing anything that would see a item added via the datasheet any differently than an item added via a normal view, but you should verify that with them.

Comment: my problem seems to lie somewhere else, see this thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17184/sharepoint-list-with-mutliple-content-types-and-the-datasheet-view

Answer (score 0):

a workflow can also trigger in datasheet. Just make sure that fields-requiring-value are not empty.

regards,
nlhizon