# SharePoint List with multiple content types and the datasheet view

Tags: content-type, datasheet

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/b9e0d1ba-318b-4449-abf9-65e526ebc024) thread. SharePoint 2010 does not "support" using the datasheet view with multiple content types configured anymore.

But maybe somebody knows a workaround for my problem:

I have a list with two content types: one custom (called audit) and one folder content type.

When I edit list items in the datashaeet view it nicely displays all the audit columns and I can edit them. 
When I try to add records I can fill in all the fields and save it. When I then try to edit or view the item from a normal AllItems.aspx, I just get a single title field containing the list item id of the folder item created.

Is there a way to tell SharePoint, that it should set this default content type to "Audit"?

I've allready tried adding a (Nintex) workflow to the newly created folder and setting the content type to audit, but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Is Audit the default content type for the list?

Comment: yes, audit is the default content type..

Comment: Have you checked the ordering of the content type on the list?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set correct `ContentTypeId` at the `ItemAdding event receiver`.

Also please note that You should set content type id from the list schema.

Answer (score 1):

Default content type is set under List Settings, beneath the Content Types section, with "Change new button order and default content type. Default will be the content type at position 1.